# Can't build/sync new or existing projects after Android Studio upgrade to 3.1

Tags: android, gradle, build, pom.xml

I've just upgraded from Android Studio 3.0.1 to 3.1 and now I can't build or use editors for any of my projects. Gradle is trying to sync but keeps failing to download some .pom files despite that fact that I can download them in a browser fine, am not using a proxy and my firewall has no outbound restrictions. I have tried *uninstalling the Kotlin plugin* and *clearing the caches/restarting* and I just can't get AS to build. I can't even get it to build/sync brand new, totally empty projects. Does anyone know how to fix or workaround this?

```
Android Studio 3.1
Build #AI-173.4670197, built on March 22, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 7 6.1
```

Here is a new, empty project about 10 minutes after being created:

[image: New empty project after control restore to user]

And here is an existing project that was building fine up until the upgrade. Now, it just spends time trying to download this file from multiple sites before failing with the same errors as in the image above:

[image]

Edit: build.gradle (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Edit: build.gradle (Module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stredgic.servicenotificationdev"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I had to bite the bullet and re-install Android Studio to fix the problem. Here are the specific steps I took for anyone who has this issue (Windows 7):

- Backed-up Android Studio settings (`File` -> `Export Settings...`)
- Uninstalled Android Studio. I elected to remove everything but this **discarded my development keys** so I had to reinstall all my apps once I got back up and running. Back them up first unless you don't mind starting from scratch
- In the `c:\Users\XXXX` folder (where XXXX is my username), I deleted the  `.gradle` and any Android Studio directories. I had actually deleted `.gradle` before while trying to fix the problem but I deleted it again after AS recreated it
- Installed the newer Android Studio 3.1 exe, freshly downloaded from Google
- Imported the settings I'd backed up earlier (`File` -> `Import Settings...`)
- Re-installed all my apps as they had been signed by the new development keys generated when I installed the newer version of Android Studio

I hope this helps anyone who has the same problem because it cost me a good 14+ hours of frustration and wasted time. I recommend that in future, if you upgrade even the smallest of Android Studio features that you:

- Do so only if it provides required functionality or fixes an issue you have
- Keep a backup machine capable of continuing development while you upgrade your primary one...
- ...or, if you don't have one... do so only at a time when you can spare a day or two of lost time

Answer (score 0):

Click the `Open File` links in the bottom right panel.

Make sure `google()` and `jcenter()` are the first two lines of `buildscript -> repositories` section in these files, put `google()` before `jcenter()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Cloudream, unfortunately those are the only two lines in that section and are already in that order